Terraform does not destroy the app registration of an Azure DevOps service endpoint
When creating a resource of type azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurecr, it creates an app registration in entra.microsoft.com, but that app registration has no regular display name (just a bunch of characters), and more importantly, the app registration is not removed when running terraform destroy. Is there a way to use Terraform to specify the display name of the app registration? And can we make it so that the app registration is removed when the azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurecr resource is removed?

Hi @limitIntegral314, what's the latest state of the issue? Have you tried my suggestion below to create an ARM SC and delete it manually to check whether the application will be deleted automatically or not?

I've just looked at your answer, and saw you're not using a azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurecr, but instead azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm. However, this requires me to manually create a service principal, which I don't want (I want everything to be fully automated).


Can you share the official terraform doc about azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurecr? Then I can test further.  2. Using azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm doesn't require you to manually create a service principal, it will create a SP automatically and be removed automatically after running terraform destroy -input=false -auto-approve.



When creating a resource of type azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurecr, it creates an app registration in entra.microsoft.com, but that app registration has no regular display name (just a bunch of characters)

According to your description, it seems that you are creating an ARM (Azure Resource Manager) service connection which authentication method is Workload Identity federation (automatic) or Service principal (automatic). When such service connection is created in Azure DevOps, an app registration will be created automatically in Microsoft Entra ID. Its name format is "OrganizationName-ProjectName-SubscriptionID", which is by default.
Take this main.tf for example,
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">= 0.1.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm" "example" {
  project_id                             = "{Your DevOps project id}"
  service_endpoint_name                  = "Terraform AzureRM"
  service_endpoint_authentication_scheme = "ServicePrincipal"
  azurerm_spn_tenantid                   = "{Your tenant id}"
  azurerm_subscription_id                = "{Your subscription id}"
  azurerm_subscription_name              = "{Your subscription name}"
}

It will create an ARM SC named "Terraform AzureRM" in DevOps.

And an app registration as shown below will be created in Microsoft Entra ID.


Is there a way to use Terraform to specify the display name of the app registration

You can't specify the display name of the app registration when the authentication method of ARM SC is automatic, but you can create an app registration manually in Microsoft Entra ID, specify its name and use it to create your SC. See azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm example usage for the scripts.

And can we make it so that the app registration is removed when the azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurecr resource is removed?

Testing terraform destroy -input=false -auto-approve, it works fine. Both ARM SC and the app registration are deleted.


When doing terraform destroy, the resource will indeed be destroyed, but the problem is that the registration still shows up in Entra (app registration that have been created weeks ago still show up there). Is there any way to also remove it from Entra itself?

Testing on my side, the app registration will also be deleted in Entra after running terraform destroy -input=false -auto-approve. You can manually create an ARM service connection which authentication method is Workload Identity federation (automatic) or Service principal (automatic). Then an application will be created in your Entra tenant. Delete the service connection manually and check whether the application will be deleted automatically or not.
